# Could a flat battery make a watch run fast?

Tags: time, crystals

My watch used to keep good time but as of about a month ago it runs fast (gains about 5 mins per day). Could a flat battery be responsible, or is this physically impossible? It's a quartz crystal watch (the usual type).

Comment: Please retag as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flat battery is not responsible in the way one might imagine an electric motor running more slowly as voltage drops.

Quartz-crystal oscillators used in watches are based on the use of **resonance**. The resonant frequency depends on physical characteristics of the quartz crystal. The resonant frequency should not be sensitive to the normal range of changes in battery voltage.

See [crystal oscillator: stability and ageing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator#Stability_and_aging) for some possible causes.